# Any limitations using CloudKit for an Enterprise, In-House Distribution iOS App?

Tags: ios, icloud, enterprise, cloudkit, in-house-distribution

Can an iOS app that will be distributed in-house (i.e. an "iOS Developer Enterprise Program" app) use CloudKit? If so, are there any limitations on what CloudKit features are available?

I've found this difficult to search for as both "enterprise" and "in-house" are overloaded an in wide use. Apple's docs on adding capabilities aren't specific enough:

> Certain app services — **such as** Game Center and In-App Purchase — are available only to iOS Developer Program and Mac Developer Program apps distributed through the store. These services require additional configuration in your Xcode project, Member Center, and sometimes iTunes Connect. **App services that don’t require iTunes Connect configuration are also available to iOS Developer Enterprise Program apps**.

That "such as" makes me concerned that isn't an exhaustive list; this is reinforced by the criteria regarding iTunes Connect configuration.

But now I can ask the question another way: does enabling iCloud require iTunes Connect configuration? If yes, is it required for all or some iCloud services (e.g. does keychain sync require iTunes Connect configs, but document and key-value storage don't)?

Comment: Did you ever find out? If so please answer your own question :-)

Comment: Yes, what was the answer?